# why shows cannot read property undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In my ionic-Angular application,I have load the content from the db and successfully printed on console, but I cannot bind with view, it says [image: Error]
    **app.html**

```
  <ion-card-content>
  {{homeContent.about}}
  </ion-card-content>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams, public 
   homeService: HomeContentService, 
  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
 this.homeService.geteventHomeContentForPage(this.event.id).subscribe(data=>
 { 
  this.homeContent=data;

  console.log(this.homeContent) 
  console.log(this.homeContent.about) 

 })
}
```

My console [image: Output console]

Comment: can you show output for `console.log(this.homeContent)`?

Comment: are u initialising `homeContent` as `homeContent: any = {}` and not just `homeContent: any` ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `homeContent` property is loaded async, so when Angular tries to render the view, `homeContent` is still not defined, and then an error is thrown when trying to access to the `about` property. To fix this, use the **elvis operator**:

```
  <ion-card-content>
    {{ homeContent?.about }}
  </ion-card-content>
```

This will tell Angular not to try to read the `about` property if the `homeContent` is still `null`/`undefined`

---

Some other ways to prevent this from happening would be to add a check with `ngIf` like this:

```
  <ion-card-content *ngIf="homeContent">
    {{ homeContent.about }}
  </ion-card-content>
```

In this case we don't need the elvis operator (?) since the entire `ion-card-content` won't be rendered if the `homeContent` property is no defined.

Another possible way to avoid this error, would be to initialize the `homeContent` property as an object, so when trying to access to its `about` sub-property, it will be null but Angular won't throw an error:

```
public homeContent: any = {};
```

Comment: Nice answer. Could you also solve it with lifecycle hook?

Comment: @FromZeroToHero I dont think so.. observables are asynchronous .. There is a possibility of data being received after view is loaded even when set in constructor

Comment: Thank you! Starting using way to many ?'s and here is a great reason to use *ngIf

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @StefanBob :)